# Angular sort data in a ascending row

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I try to sort data depending on the timestamp of the data set. To do so I created this service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}) export class BlogService {
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  getStudents() {
    return this.afs.collection('Blogs', ref => ref.orderBy('ts')).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

At the moment I receive the data in a ascending order but i want to receive it in a descending order, which means the newest value first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sould work as expected,

```
import {orderBy} from "lodash";

getStudents(){
   return this.afs.collection('Blogs', ref => orderBy(ref, ['ts'], ['desc'])).valueChanges();
 }
```

Comment: I was about write this ans :)

Comment: doesnt work unfortunately i receive this error: ERROR in src/app/blog.service.ts(14,32): error TS2345: Argument of type '"Blogs"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CollectionReference'.